# Custom gallery view in android

Tags: android, gallery

I want to make custom gallery view in android where i have to show 3 images on screen following.

[image]

[image]

[image]

while flinging on gallery view the images should look like in this pattern?
I have also tried [cover flow example](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html) after making some changes. that is giving that same effect but it puts selected image always in center where I have to show 1st child at left side | 2nd child in middle | 3rd child in right side.

Please share your suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe look at Android's Gallery component in AOSP?

Answer (score 1):

If it is only three images, I suggest you create a custom View.

You can create a class that extends View. There you can have a drawable or bitmap. Then you draw on canvas by overwriting onDraw() method.

On your Activity you create an ArrayList that contains 3 Views (the class I described above) and then you create an animation to translate in the Z direction when the image is clicked. Example of z animation with rotation here: http://www.ece301.com/android/63-android-animation-flip-image.html